# Get collection with promotional products not working

Tags: product, magento-1, collection, product-listing

I need to get a collection listing all products with a promotion, but I'm getting this error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function getBackend() on boolean
```

I tried those 2 solutions, but still getting the same error:

First try:

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection')->addAttributeToSelect('*')->addAttributeToFilter('promotion', 1);
```

Second try:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*')->addAttributeToFilter('promotion', 1);
```

How can I solve that and get the list with only promotional products? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved changing my line to:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*')->addAttributeToFilter('special_price', array('notnull' => true));
```